# How to ensure data imported matches sklearn requirements for processing?

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am trying to get started on some machine learning on SKlearn I am getting this massive error that I have no idea where to start

*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14812/623750250.py in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,y_train)
      2 predictions = model.predict(X_test)

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[38.66999816894531, 39.125, 37.0, 37.29999923706055, 31.34000015258789, 31.0, 32.54999923706055, 32.0, 28.64999961853027, 30.5, 30.25, 30.0, 28.68000030517578, 30.13999938964844, 34.5, 34.5, 33.38000106811523,
```

- 

This is my code:

```
df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/radoy/Programming/ML Chart Patterns/xx_combined.xlsx')
X = df.drop(columns=['consolidating'])
y = df['consolidating']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y, test_size=0.2)

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()

model.fit(X_train,y_train)
predictions = model.predict(X_test)

score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)
score
```

And this is an excerpt of the data, a lot of lists of different lengths. I have about 100 lines of data and am aware that this is highly insufficient, but I just want to get started from somewhere.

[image]

Comment: It appears that some of the numeric data was parsed as strings. Try `df.types` to show you the data types within the DataFrame

Comment: this is what i have **periods           int64
opens            object
highs            object
lows             object
closes           object
volumes          object
consolidating     int64
dtype: object**

Comment: What is this data describing? How was it produced?

Comment: I have uploaded some data here: [link](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/00748e1bdc9b6dd5c3bffcce3ca3d94c20220603071725/b515aa). Basically, the data describes a collection of stocks' price charts. I have also attached a sample of a single stock (OHLC which stands for open price, high price, low price, and close price) and also I have attached the code that I use to loop through a folder full of single stocks and add those to a single file data source to be used for training. 1 row in the xx_combined file represents data for 1 stock. Column "consolidating" is a label if pattern is consolidating

Comment: Any other ideas ? It seems its more like a pandas issue then.

Comment: You have a list in a string. that is not an appropriate datatype. You need to move the values in the list to another column so that you will have one numeric value per column

Comment: I do not want to have one value per column, I want to have a list of floats in that column  but when I try to convert it I get error **ValueError: could not convert string to float: '[76.77999877929688, 78.18000030517578, 75.69000244140625, 73.37000274658203, 70.6500015258789, 71.44999694824219, 72.0, 72.0, 72.9800033569336, 69.5999984741211... ** . If I check the data types before saving the data to csv file it shows the columns are int64 but I still cannot convert them to a list of floats ..

Comment: can you reproduce some rows from your dataframe to test with them? it might be that the values in the list are strings as well